# What is fTestnetToBeDeprecatedFieldRPC seen in chainparams.cpp?

Tags: bitcoind

`fTestnetToBeDeprecatedFieldRPC` is a `bool` type variable set to some values in the `main`, `testnet` and `regtest`in `chainparams.cpp`. What is the use of this value ?

Answer (score 2):

The field corresponds to false for mainnet, true for testnet, and false for regtest. You can think of it as a flag that tells you whether the current network is testnet.

#### Why's it named like that?

To get people to not use it, and because `getinfo` and `getmininginfo` still use it:

> jtimon commented:
>
> Yeah, comparing to the testnet id was very readable so it's the new flag. The difference is that when people see "NetworkID() == something" they think they can use that too, while FlagWithLongNameIncludingTheWordDeprecated() is not as likely to be used or that's my hope.
> @laanwj explained the deprecation thing, but basically, RPCs can just use bip70's networkidstring()
> For the string, I was going to create another flag but @laanwj wants to keep chainparams clean of GUI-related things. Of course comparing to an enumerator is better than comparing to a string, again, the goal is that people don't see the comparation to the enumeration and think they can call CChainParams::NetworkID(), hopefully the comparison with a string will make people use that approach less, but we need the string for BIP70 anyway.

[(Source.)](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/4802#issuecomment-54269146)